# iOS and Android App Shell for website - What technology works best? WebView? Progressive App?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, webview

What is the proper way to have an app shell that simply loads a website. and properly handles orientation, etc?

We are releasing our app in a fragmented roll out - We have our mobile website completed, but require a native app to download, we will be swapping the 'guts' of our app in a few months with proper native code, so want to simply open the website up if people download our app *for now*

I found stuff like this
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

I also know that a webview can be used, but is that the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, `WKWebView` is definitely the way to go moving forward after iOS 8.0 with its technology almost similar to Safari's Web View Controller. It is highly customizable and you may want to check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) here to learn more.